# Panning Bokeh GMap programmatically

Tags: python-3.x, plot, data-visualization, bokeh

Is it possible to adjust the centre coordinate of a bokeh google map plot and refresh the plot? I'm intending to centre the selected point according to user input in a bokeh TextInput field.

A piece of example code for displaying the map is shown below.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(<...>))

origin = (<...>, <...>)
options = GMapOptions(lat=origin[0], lng=origin[1], map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)
tools = "crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,reset,save"
location_map = gmap(environ.get('API_KEY'), options, title="Station locations", tools=tools, active_scroll="wheel_zoom")
r = location_map.circle(x="lng", y="lat", size=15, fill_color='color', fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is kind of old, but I think I found the answer. I know that GMapPlot used in Bokeh has an update function that allows you to update existing parameters. I'm pretty sure that gmap is very similar to GMapPlot so...

```
    options = GMapOptions(lat=origin[0], lng=origin[1], map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)
    location_map = gmap(environ.get('API_KEY'), map_options=options, title="Station locations", tools=tools, active_scroll="wheel_zoom")
    
    updated_options = GMapOptions(lat=new_lat, lng=new_lng, zoom=new_zoom)
    location_map.update(map_options=updated_options)
```

Sorry if the formatting is off. It's my first post.